# Return Fragment Instance in Kotlin @JvmStatic

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

Kotlin in standard generate something like this

```
   @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
                MyFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                    }
                }
```

What do @JvmStatic ?

We can do something like:

```
fun getInstance() = MyFragment()
```

and this funcion doing this same (except params)

So @JvmStatic is useless ?

Comment: It matters when you are calling the method from Java. It's in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

It "doesn't matter" for Kotlin, but if you're using this from Java then it will be "translated" into a static method. There are no equivalents of static methods in kotlin so this is the way to tell the JVM that when used from java this will translate to a static method.

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html):

> Specifies that an additional static method needs to be generated from
>   this element if it's a function.